# How to add a git repository that is a subdirectory of an existing repository?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a project with the following structure:

```
ProjA
Controllers
Models
Subprojects
     /SubProject1
     /SubProject1
```

I want to make it so that when someone clones `ProjA` that it brings down the git repos for `SubProject1` and `SubProject2`.

I attempted to do this using `git submodule` like so:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/myAccount/ProjA Subprojects/SubProject1
```

And that *seemed* to work but when I pulled down `ProjA` to a new directory my SubProjects were empty.  When I go back to the original and look at the results of `git status` it shows:

```
modified:   Subprojects/SubProject1 (modified content)
modified:   teSubprojectst/SubProject2 (modified content, untracked content)
```

Doing a `git commit...` doesn't seem to change anything.  Have I missed a step along the way that would allow me to include those directories in the parent repo?

**NOTE** I just noticed that when I try to navigate to the subprojects in github it throws a 404 error.  Not sure if I messed something up when I created them using `submodule`?  When I attempt to use `--recurse-submodules` I get a not found error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+clone

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to recurse on the submodules when you are cloning.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/myAccount/ProjA
```

Check out the docs for it here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: So I just noticed that when I attempt to navigate to the subprojects in github I get a 404 error - I can no longer view the content of those folders...  When I attempt to do this it prompts me to log in for each project and fails with my credentials